# How do I enable Ruby syntax highlighting in Neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm a new user of Neovim and trying to figure out how to enable syntax highlighting for Ruby.

What config should i edit?

edit:

This is my current config:

```
➜  ~  cat ~/.nvimrc
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set tabstop=2
set number
set noswapfile
" Automatically indent on new lines
set autoindent
" Copy the indentation of the previous line if auto indent doesn't know what to do
set copyindent
" Indenting a line with >> or << will indent or un-indent by 2
set shiftwidth=2
" Pressing tab in insert mode will use 4 spaces
set softtabstop=2
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab
" [SEARCH]
:set incsearch
:set hlsearch
" <Ctrl-l> redraws the screen and removes any search highlighting.
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>
```

And this is the error i get when loading Neovim:

```
➜  ~  nvim test.rb
Error detected while processing /Users/user/.nvimrc:
line    2:
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/HEAD/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neovim uses the xdg specification for their config files.  If you are already using vim. (If you are transferring from an old version of neovim `~/.nvimrc` is now `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` and `~/.nvim` is now `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim`)

```
mkdir -p ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:=$HOME/.config}
ln -s ~/.vim $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim
ln -s ~/.vimrc $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim
```

should get you close to running with neovim (This might not work for all plugins but its a start).

---

All you should need in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` is the following

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

to get syntax highlighting for ruby.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately adding your changes to .nvimrc generated an error.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @SharkLaser update neovim. Your runtime files appear to be out of date.

Comment: thank you! That was the final hurdle. I updated neovim via `brew update && brew reinstall --HEAD neovim`

Comment: @FDinoff have you tried neovim? I haven't given it a try. how do you think about it? good? I mean first, as good as vim?

Comment: @Kent I have not tried neovim. I've just been following the development.